# Android - User added image with ID similar to "R.Drawable"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to find a solution to index user added picture as it is in default folders (res\drawables).

My class Place

```
Place(String name, String country, String info, String sights, int photoId)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
    this.info = info;
    this.sights = sights;
    this.photoId = photoId;
}
```

Programmatically added place

```
new Place("Paris", "France", getString(R.string.paris), getString(R.string.paris_sighs), R.drawable.paris));
```

Programmatically but in-running app added place

```
new Place(
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name)).getText().toString(),
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_country)).getText().toString(),
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_about)).getText().toString(),
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sights)).getText().toString(),
            *Here I need to add image*
         );
```

I have image prepared in bitmap but I don't know how could I put it in here. Everything I know at the moment is that I can't add anything to drawable folder in running program. I am sorry if this is duplicity thread. If so post a link here for me. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you take the image from?

Comment: @ErenisR From gallery or whatever app user choose. Simple use of intent and then saving it to bitmap.

Comment: Well, then probably its better if you send Bitmap instead of int as parameter

Comment: @ErenisR Well, it's not that easy. Whole database is working on this so I would need to start almost from the beginning.. Also working with ID's like this is more simple. (But probably not in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote under my question it's not good idea to work with res ID's like this in this case. I remade my project so that database is working with Blobs.

And simply compresing via `ByteArrayOutputStream` and decoding back through `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)`.

Class Place is now working with `Bitmap` instead of `Integer`.